# SDK manager and AVD manager not running

Tags: java, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

I work with Windows 10 and Android Studio.

When I press the button "SDK manager", nothing happens.
When I open the "AVD Manager", window that opens is the "Create AVD", but when I set a new AVD, well, nothing happens.

Of course, I defined JAVA_PATH, SDK location and everything else (including sdk\tools\android.bat - java.exe).

Android studio and SDK installed in D drive, JDK and JRE installed in C drive.
Is there anything else I can do? Is there a way to spend an error report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think the problem in the build of Windows 10. There are many programs that do not work, and there are also a lot of feedback on it.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I do have kind of problem like this.
You can try running sdk manager with Run as administrator from your drive where it is located at.
let me know if it helps you if not please let us know the best solution you get from others friend . :)

Comment: did you set your sdk path properly  ? if not please do it like this 
go to
 file-->ProjectStructure-->
chose SDKLocation and set you sdk path
like this
/home/view9/Android Tools/android-sdk